# How can I make a login just like on wordpress.org?

Tags: login

The page I am talking about is this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ It is simple and perfect in my opinion. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should give you the same look unless your theme's css overwrites it:

```
<form name="loginformfooter" class="loginform" id="loginformfooter" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post">
<p><label>Username      <input type="text" value="" maxlength="40" size="13" id="user_login" name="user_login" class="text">
  </label>
    <label>Password     <input type="password" maxlength="40" size="13" id="password" name="password" class="text">
    </label>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="re">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" id="submit" name="Submit" class="button-secondary">
    (<a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">forgot?</a>) or <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=register">Register</a></p>
</form>
```